# JComboBox comboBox=new JComboBox(); is showing tex strike through on "new JComboBox()"

Tags: jcombobox, strikethrough

I was trying to -read and log serial port data using JAVA, but while adding JComboBox, the "new JComboBox" is getting strike through and showing error as- "java: cannot infer type arguments for javax.swing.JComboBox<>".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmsYP.png)

Read from a Serial port, notifying when data arrives : COM Port